# Is there a reliable approach to block Facebook's new stealth ads?

Tags: facebook, ad-blocker

Facebook has recently started inserting advertisements into my feed, where they are disguised as posts from friends and organizations I follow. My ad blocker seems unable to recognize these as advertisements, but can be configured to block specific markup. Unfortunately, as near as I can tell, Facebook has been aggressive in obfuscating the markup for such posts, making them hard to distinguish from real posts.

Is there distinctive markup in Facebook's new stealth ads that can be used to identify them. Are then ad blockers that can do this?

Comment: Your feed **where** - in the browser, in Messenger, ...?

Comment: @JanDoggen: Anywhere, but browsers primarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adblock Plus [now copes](https://adblockplus.org/blog/fb-reblock-ad-blocking-community-finds-workaround-to-facebook) with Facebook's stealth ads through it's EasyList filter. All you have to do is enable that, or manually ad

```
facebook.com##DIV[id^="substream_"] ._5jmm[data-dedupekey][data-cursor][data-xt][data-xt-vimpr="1"][data-ftr="1"][data-fte="1"]
```

to your custom filters.

Answer (score 1):

[F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) seems like it will do what you are looking for. I have not used it recently as I do not use Facebook anymore but I remember it having lots of settings for removing annoying content. It also had a button on every post you could click to hide all of that specific type of content. Check out the [features page](http://www.fbpurity.com/features.htm) to see the full list.

Comment: That looks promising, but it uses Tampermonkey, which is pretty hacky. Any idea if there's something less intrusive and that messes less with low level stuff?

Comment: No I do not know of anything else. I also don't see how using Tampermonkey is hacky or low level. Both adblock and F.B. Purity are just scripts, one is made for blocking ads, the other specifically for cleaning facebook. If you are unsure of scripts in Tampermonkey you can read through the source code or write your own userscripts.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see how it works.